# Finding Eigen Values of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to find non-trivial eigen values of the BVP $$y''(x)+\lambda y(x) =0, \quad y \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \right) = 0, \quad y(0)= -3y'(0).$$
However, after few routine calculations, I obtained $\tan ^2 (\sqrt{\lambda} \pi/2) = 9\lambda$. It is also given that the eigen values may be given by $\lambda_n = 4n^2 \pi ^2$. I am unable to show the given solutions satisfy the equation  $\tan ^2 (\sqrt{\lambda} \pi/2) = 9\lambda$.

Comment: I got that the non-trivial eigenvalues are found when $\lambda > 0$ and given implicitly by $$\tan \left( \sqrt{\lambda} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \right) = 3 \sqrt{\lambda}$$

Comment: well, I might be wrong, but I got $\tan \sqrt{\lambda}\frac{\pi}{2} = -3\sqrt{\lambda}$ before squaring.

Comment: \begin{align} \lambda > 0 \implies y &= A \cos \sqrt{\lambda} x + B \sin \sqrt{\lambda} x \\\\ y \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) &= A \cos \sqrt{\lambda} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} + B \sin \sqrt{\lambda} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \\ &= 0 \\ \implies A &= -B \tan \sqrt{\lambda} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \\\\ y(0) &= -3y'(0) \\ \implies A &= -3 B \sqrt{\lambda} \\\\ \therefore -3 B \sqrt{\lambda} &= -B \tan \sqrt{\lambda} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \\ \implies B &= 0 \text{ or } \tan \sqrt{\lambda} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} = 3 \sqrt{\lambda}\end{align}

Comment: Right, thank you. My calculation was wrong. But how to show that the given values satisfy this equation?

Comment: You can't because they don't. Try it yourself. In your DE, set $$\lambda = 4n^{2}\pi^{2} = (2 n \pi)^{2} \implies y = A \cos(2n \pi x) + B \sin(2n \pi x)$$ Hence $$y(0) = -3 y'(0) \implies A = - 6n \pi B$$ and so $$y \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) = -6n \pi B \cos \left( 2n \pi \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right) + B \sin \left( 2n \pi \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \ne 0 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$ unless $B = 0 \implies A = 0$ which would be trivial. The solution is wrong.

Comment: The eigenvalues do not have a closed form. You can only find them numerically

Comment: @Mattos I think you have enough in your comments to make it an answer

Comment: @Mattos I also think so. If $ y(0) , y^{'}(0) $ are unrelated real constants then we have harmonic motion and even spaced eigen values.

Comment: @Mattos I agree with you.

Comment: The formulation makes it seem as if the information in the question comes from two different tasks. Having $\pi$ in the eigenvalue and having $\pi$ in the interval ends is usually mutually exclusive. Here for large $λ$ one needs to be close to the poles of the tangent function, that is $\sqrtλ\frac\pi2\approx(2n+1)\frac\pi2$ or $λ\approx(2n+1)^2$ without $\pi$ factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ease of notation, let $\lambda = \omega^2$, then the general solution is

$$ y(x) = A\cos(\omega x) + B\sin(\omega x) $$

The first B.C. gives

$$ y(0) = -3y'(0) \implies A = -3\omega B $$
$$ \implies Y(x) = B\big[{-3}\omega\cos(\omega x) + \sin(\omega x)\big] $$

The second B.C. gives

$$ y\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 0 \implies {-3}\omega\cos\left(\frac{\omega\pi}{2}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{\omega\pi}{2}\right) \\ 
\implies 3\omega = \tan\left(\frac{\omega\pi}{2}\right) $$

These eigenvalues do not have a closed form and will need to be solved numerically. However, as $\omega \to \infty$, you have the asymptotic approximation

$$ \cos\left(\frac{\omega\pi}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{3\omega}\sin\left(\frac{\omega\pi}{2}\right) \approx  \cos\left(\frac{\omega\pi}{2}\right) = 0 $$

The solutions will we very close to the zeroes of the cosine function, hence
$$ \omega_{n\to\infty} \approx 2n+1 $$

For very large values of $\omega$